# Serialize/Deserialize list of objects using json and python

Tags: python, json, serialization

How do i serialize a list of objects(Person) to a json file and then read that json file back and deserialize them back into objects? I know how to write to a json file but i'm not clear on how to convert my objects to json properly.

Below is my simplified snippet of code. I have a list containing two people and i want to serialize them and save to a json file. Then deserialize them back to objects of type People.

Thanks for the help.

```
import json

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, nickname):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 0
        self.nickname = nickname

# create a few people
A = Person('John', 'Joker')
B = Person('Marisa', 'Snickerdoodle')

# add people to list
peeps = []
peeps.append(A)
peeps.append(B)

# dummy data saving to json for testing
data = {
   'name' : 'ACME',
   'shares' : 100,
   'price' : 542.23
}

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `json` module expects lists, dicts, strings, numbers, booleans, and None, not custom classes. You need to make a dictionary out of your `People` instance. A simple way to do this is with `vars(A)`.

Comment: could you elaborate or show an example of how I could do this ?

Comment: @JokerMartini Try `print(vars(A))` and see what happens.

Comment: that works pretty well. If I do that, how can I read it back from json and convert to Person object ?

Comment: @JokerMartini easiest way would be to add `age=0` to `Person.__init__` and then call `Person(**json.load(infile))`.

Comment: is this suggest solution for serialization good practice or would it be more ideal going the route suggested by ravi.  I ask because I'm build an app which I don't want to start off in the wrong direction.

Comment: @JokerMartini there is no 'good practice' that I know, you're just going back and forth between classes and dicts. It's simple stuff and you don't need to think about it too hard, I was just showing how to avoid boilerplate but do what feels right. Also consider the pickle suggestion, it will be the easiest if you don't need other languages to be able to read the data.

Comment: thank you so much for your patience and answering my questions ,I'm not the most advanced python user. Just to be clear which method is considered the pickle method ?

Comment: pickle is a module that can handle arbitrary types but restricts you to python. See juanpa's answer.

Answer (score 2):

add to_dict method to your person class. try this

```
In [2]: class Person(object):
   ...:         def __init__(self, name, nickname):
   ...:                 self.name = name
   ...:                 self.age = 0
   ...:                 self.nickname = nickname
   ...:         def to_dict(self):
   ...:             data = {}
   ...:             data['name'] = self.name
   ...:             data['age'] = self.age
   ...:             return data
   ...:         
peeps = []
peeps.append(A.to_dict())
peeps.append(B.to_dict())

In [9]: with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
   ...:     json.dump(peeps, outfile)

In [10]: !cat data.json
[{"age": 0, "name": "John"}, {"age": 0, "name": "Marisa"}]
```

Update:
To deserialize json to python object

```
In [4]: with open('data.json', 'r') as infile:
   ....     data = json.loads(infile.read())
   ...:     
In [5]: A = Person(data[0]['name'], data[0]['nickname'])
```

Comment: thanks for the help . You show how to write peraon to json, how can  I read back from json file and convert to an object type Person.

Comment: @JokerMartini Updated Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot serialize custom classes using JSON.

You should use the `pickle` module instead. From the docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-json

> JSON, by default, can only represent a subset of the Python built-in
>   types, **and no custom classes**;

Emphasis mine.

Also, from http://www.json.org/:

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, **dictionary**, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, **list**, or sequence.

Again, emphasis is mine. In python, you can serialize dictionaries or lists that contain values, where values can be:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method for the class to deserialize json

```
import json

class Person:
   ...
   def from_json(self, j):
       self.__dict__ = json.loads(j)
```